# User list displaying each user twice?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Think something might be wrong with this code? It all seems to work alright except it is showing double of the same user. Each user shows twice in the list? Is there something I am missing here?

```
    <?
                                        $sql6= "SELECT username, email_address FROM users WHERE blocked='1'";

$result6 = mysql_query($sql6);

while($user6 = mysql_fetch_array($result6)){
              $user = $user6['username'];
              $email = $user6['email_address'];

              $displayblocked .= '<font color="#FF0000"><strong>'. $user .'</strong></font> | '. $email .'<br/>';
    print "$displayblocked";
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're concatenating your `$displayblocked` string and also outputting it in a loop - the concatenated string will be outputted on every loop iteration.

So, if you have two users - the first one will be outputted twice and the second one once. If you have three users, the first will be outputted three times, the second twice and the third once ... etc =]

There are two things you could do here; the first is don't concat the string and still output it during every iteration:

```
$displayblocked = '<font color="#FF0000"><strong>'. $user .'</strong></font> | '. $email .'<br/>';
print "$displayblocked";
```

The second is to move the `print` statement outside of the loop and still concat within it:

```
while($user6 = mysql_fetch_array($result6)){
    $user = $user6['username'];
    $email = $user6['email_address'];

    $displayblocked .= '<font color="#FF0000"><strong>'. $user .'</strong></font> | '. $email .'<br/>';
}

print "$displayblocked";
```